# Java fundamental - a little confusion on return type and return statement in methods

Tags: java, return

My understanding is that in Java if a method declare a return type, compilation fails if we don't put a return statement in the method. But the following code compiles successfully.

```
 public int test() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
```

Now I am a little confused. I think my understanding is wrong. Can someone please clarify?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Java method must either return, or throw an exception. The compiler refuses to compile if all the possible code paths don't lead to either a return or an exception. The unique code path in this method throws an exception, so it's valid.

What would be invalid would be this, because if `i <= 0`, nothing is returned, and no exception is thrown:

```
public int test() throws Exception {
    int i = new Random().nextInt();
    if (i > 0) { 
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
}
```

It would be valid if changed to

```
public int test() throws Exception {
    int i = new Random().nextInt();
    if (i > 0) { 
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add that it s the normal way to return a value. Excelption are a different mechanism to deal with errors that can happen. Both are not equal and the exception mechanism should not be used in place of a return to provide an additional way to communicate values to a caller.