# My method keeps saying I need to return a string but my method has a return statement that returns a string

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a method that is suppose to go get a JSON object that has all the champion ids from league of legends and I want it to return the name of the champion based on the "number" that is passed to the method from another loop in the program.

```
public String getChampionName(int number) //where it is saying its not returning a string
{
    try
    {
        String JSonChampionName = readURL("myURLwithAPIkey");
        JSONObject object = JSONObject.fromObject(JSonChampionName);
        JSONObject championData = (JSONObject)(object.get("data"));
        JSONObject champName = (JSONObject)(championData.get(number));
        if(object != null && championData != null && champName != null)
        {
            String cName = champName.get("name").toString();
            return cName;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }catch(Exception v){}
}
```

Any ideas I am just not sure why its telling me the method is not returning a string.

Comment: What would happen in this method if an exception was thrown?  Then no string would be returned.  That's why its complaining.

Comment: If an exception gets thrown and you catch it ... what exactly are you returning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java fundamental - a little confusion on return type and return statement in methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287717/java-fundamental-a-little-confusion-on-return-type-and-return-statement-in-met)

Comment: Additionally: when you're dropping exceptions, you probably need to rethink your program's logic.

Answer (score 1):

What if there is an `Exception` caught?  In that case your method doesn't have a `return` statement.

Either don't catch the `Exception`, or provide a `return` statement in the case that the `Exception` is caught.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is saying you need to return a string on every possible path that the program could take.  If an exception occurs, you will catch it, but your catch block will do nothing; then the program will fall to the end of the method without returning anything.

You need to fix your method so that if an exception is caught, you either return something, or throw some other exception.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to return the type expected in all scenarios!! Thats what compiler expects.

Right now , with the code that you implemented , the problem is that in case of an exception this method does not return anything...

Thats why compiler is complaining even though you have a return statement..